# Zipkin + Elasticsearch (ELK) not create index

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos7, zipkin

**Hi everyone!**

I have "ELK" (6.4.2) working perfectly with filebeat, metricbeat, packetbeat and winlogbeat in CentOS 7 x86_64 (Kernel 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64).

I'm trying to integrate zipkin + elk (see https://logz.io/blog/zipkin-elk/), but Elasticsearch does not create indices with Kibana.

When trying to create the indices in Kibana, the process does not end. (Follow logs below).

I suspect the zipkin connection drivers are not compatible with elk 6.4.2. Has anyone had the same problem and has a "light at the end of the tunnel"?

**Tks for all!**

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Zipkin startup:

```
java -DSTORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch -DES_HOSTS=http://localhost:9200 -jar /opt/zipkin.io/bin/zipkin.jar
```

Error log in Elasticsearch:

```
[2018-10-24T11:31:59,933][WARN ][o.e.d.i.m.MapperService  ] Setting index.mapper.dynamic is deprecated since indices may not have more than one type anymore.
[2018-10-24T11:31:59,936][WARN ][o.e.d.i.m.MapperService  ] [_default_] mapping is deprecated since it is not useful anymore now that indexes cannot have more than one type
[2018-10-24T11:31:59,954][WARN ][o.e.d.i.m.MapperService  ] Setting index.mapper.dynamic is deprecated since indices may not have more than one type anymore.
[2018-10-24T11:32:00,033][WARN ][o.e.d.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] index or alias name [zipkin:span-2018-10-24] containing ':' is deprecated and will not be supported in Elasticsearch 7.0+
[2018-10-24T11:32:00,245][WARN ][o.e.d.i.m.MapperService  ] Setting index.mapper.dynamic is deprecated since indices may not have more than one type anymore.
[2018-10-24T11:33:47,717][WARN ][o.e.d.a.a.i.t.p.PutIndexTemplateRequest] Deprecated field [template] used, replaced by [index_patterns]
```

Comment: check the version required by zipkin

Comment: also , the index will not be created untill the application start sending traces

Answer (score 0):

Here is the related issue:

```
we also mentioned recently that for data to appear, applications need to be
sending traces

https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin#quick-start

you can tell also by hitting the /metrics endpoint and look at stats named
collector
```

https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/1939

Comment: Hi Khan,

My apps send traces to the zipkin with no problem. As shown in the initial post the problem is in the zipkin connection with elasticsearch.

Tks.

Comment: @BlenoLopes there is not connection errors in the post

Comment: @Khan Network connection error really does not exist. As said, problem being solved as bug in app between zipkin and elasticsearch, specifically in the versions I'm using. Tks for you help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I opened a issue on the zipkin github, a theme already being treated as a bug.

Initial thread:
https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/2218#issuecomment-432876510

Bug track:
https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/2219

Tks for all!